# Advanced custom field (wordpress plugin of same name) not showing

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I've set up some fields using the advanced custom fields.

I’ve created a custom field and a post that uses that custom field. I’m trying to display it on a page like this:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'Portfolio Item' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<p>' . the_title() . '</p>';
    echo '<a href="#">' . the_field('portfolio_url') . '</a>';
endwhile;
?>
```

The title displays no problem, but the custom field does not i.e. the output is just:

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

The name ‘portfolio_url’ is the ‘Field Name’.

Can anyone help with what I’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try and send in smaller snippets of code.
Or give an online example.

Basically if you add a the_field('bottom_quote') function on your page it should echo out the current pages' "bottom_quote" field.

If you're not in a WP loop you have to explicitly point to the post you want to get the field from of using an ID:

```
<?php the_field( 'bottom_quote', $post->ID );
```

Also note that $post should either be global or in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the post_type parameter is allowed to have a space.  Check that you're using the correct slug for that first.

Comment: It must be correct because the_title() works no problem, so I know that it is at least receiving the object from the database.

Comment: ok but I've never seen one used with a space before, I think it's worth double checking to rule it out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not to familiar with this specific plugin but you may need to call in the `global $variable` that I know when using a class like WPAlchemy you need to call `$meta`

Check here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta